# Extract mantissa, exponent and sign data from IEEE-754 double in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, floating-point, double, floating-point-conversion

How to extract mantissa, exponent and sign data from an IEEE-754 64-bit (double) floating-point number in VBA?  Thanks

**Edit** (after John Coleman comments). Before posting the original question, I have looked around for a solution and could only find how to do it in C (e.g. using structures with bit fields).  Couldn't find anything for VBA.  I have tried using VBA's bit operators (i.e. AND, OR, NOT, XOR) but this does not seem to give the expected result.  For example, 1 expressed in single precision IEEE 32-bit floating-point is represented by

### 0 01111111 00000000000000000000000

where the first bit is for sign, the next 8 bits are for the (biased) exponent, and the last 23 bits are for the mantissa.  Applying NOT to 1 should return

### 1 10000000 11111111111111111111111

which is -3.9999998 in decimal, but the following code in VBA returns -2, which is represented by

### 1 10000000 00000000000000000000000

```
x = Not 1!
Debug.Print x
```

I didn't see the point of posting this in my OP.

Comment: A down-vote?  I guess it has come from a VBA-hater. Oh well.

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted your question, but I find it understandable enough why someone might. It doesn't seem like you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It looks like you haven't researched very much. You certainly haven't provided any code which shows what you have tried and where it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for taking your time to look at my post.   I have expanded my OP after your comment.

Comment: A very similar question would be “how can I find/implement the equivalent of the `frexp` function in VBA?”. Googling for this does not turn up any immediate solution hidden in VBA's standard library, but does turn up some attempts are implementing this functionality with floating-point operations. You could get inspiration from these. It just seems like VBA is the wrong language to access the bits of the representation of a floating-point number.

Comment: @Confounded Thank you for adding some details. I upvoted the question since it does seem interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the way to do this.  The following function `DoubleToBin` returns a string of 64 bits representing an IEEE-754 double floating-point number. It uses a VBA "trick" to pass around raw data without using API routines (such as MemCopy (RtlMoveMemory)) by combining `LSet` with User Defined Types of the same size.  And once we have the bit string we can extract all components from it.

```
Type TDouble
  Value As Double
End Type

Type TArray
  Value(1 To 8) As Byte
End Type

Function DoubleToArray(DPFloat As Double) As Variant
  Dim A As TDouble
  Dim B As TArray
  A.Value = DPFloat 
  LSet B = A
  DoubleToArray = B.Value
End Function

Function DoubleToBin(DPFloat As Double) As String
  Dim ByteArray() As Byte
  Dim BitString As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer

  ByteArray = DoubleToArray(DPFloat)

  For i = 8 To 1 Step -1
    j = 2 ^ 7
    Do While j >= 1
      If (ByteArray(i) And j) = 0 Then
        BitString = BitString & "0"
      Else
        BitString = BitString & "1"
      End If
      j = j \ 2
    Loop
  Next i

  DoubleToBin = BitString
End Function
```

How does it work on here - do I now accept my own answer?

Comment: Nice! I modified it slightly (see my second answer). Stack Overflow meta is the place to go with questions like "is it okay to accept my own answer?" See, for example, this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252491/how-would-i-award-my-own-eureka-moment/252492#252492

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification of Confounded's excellent answer. I modified their function to be use the built-in function `Hex` rather than bit-wise operations to get the to the bit patterns, made it be able to handle both single and double precision flexibly, and return either the results in either hex (the default) or binary:

```
Type TDouble
  Value As Double
End Type

Type TSingle
  Value As Single
End Type

Type DArray
  Value(1 To 8) As Byte
End Type

Type SArray
  Value(1 To 4) As Byte
End Type

Function DoubleToArray(DPFloat As Double) As Variant
  Dim A As TDouble
  Dim B As DArray
  A.Value = DPFloat
  LSet B = A
  DoubleToArray = B.Value
End Function

Function SingleToArray(SPFloat As Single) As Variant
  Dim A As TSingle
  Dim B As SArray
  A.Value = SPFloat
  LSet B = A
  SingleToArray = B.Value
End Function

Function HexToBin(hDigit As String) As String
    Select Case hDigit
        Case "0": HexToBin = "0000"
        Case "1": HexToBin = "0001"
        Case "2": HexToBin = "0010"
        Case "3": HexToBin = "0011"
        Case "4": HexToBin = "0100"
        Case "5": HexToBin = "0101"
        Case "6": HexToBin = "0110"
        Case "7": HexToBin = "0111"
        Case "8": HexToBin = "1000"
        Case "9": HexToBin = "1001"
        Case "A": HexToBin = "1010"
        Case "B": HexToBin = "1011"
        Case "C": HexToBin = "1100"
        Case "D": HexToBin = "1101"
        Case "E": HexToBin = "1110"
        Case "F": HexToBin = "1111"
    End Select
End Function

Function ByteToString(B As Byte, Optional FullBinary As Boolean = False)
    Dim BitString As String
    BitString = Hex(B)
    If Len(BitString) < 2 Then BitString = "0" & BitString
    If FullBinary Then
        BitString = HexToBin(Mid(BitString, 1, 1)) & HexToBin(Mid(BitString, 2, 1))
    End If
    ByteToString = BitString
End Function

Function FloatToBits(float As Variant, Optional FullBinary As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim ByteArray() As Byte
    Dim BitString As String
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim x As Double, y As Single
    If TypeName(float) = "Double" Then
        n = 8
        x = float
        ByteArray = DoubleToArray(x)
    ElseIf TypeName(float) = "Single" Then
        n = 4
        y = float
        ByteArray = SingleToArray(y)
    Else
        FloatToBits = "Error!"
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = n To 1 Step -1
        BitString = BitString & ByteToString(ByteArray(i), FullBinary)
    Next i
    FloatToBits = BitString
End Function
```

Here is a test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Single, y As Double
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()
    y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()

    Debug.Print FloatToBits(x)
    Debug.Print FloatToBits(x, True)
    Debug.Print FloatToBits(y)
    Debug.Print FloatToBits(y, True)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
40490FDB
01000000010010010000111111011011
400921FB54442D18
0100000000001001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000
```

When I feed 400921FB54442D18 into [this](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html) online tool I get back 3.141592653589793, which makes perfect sense.

Somewhat curiously, when I apply this to 10.4 I get

0100000000100100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101

which differs in the final place from the example in [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rounding.htm) excellent article on floats in Excel VBA. Both versions round to 10.4 (to many, many places). I don't quite know what to make of the discrepancy.

Comment: Very nice. About the discrepancy in the case of using 10.4 - could it be about "round-half-to-even" vs "round-to-nearest-value"?  I think the former will return the same result as you get.  Have a look at this tool [link](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/)

Comment: PS. "round-half-to-even" is one of several round-to-nearest-value methods, so in my previous comment it should have stated: “round-half-to-even” vs some other method.

Comment: @Confounded That makes perfect sense. 10.4 = 10 + 2/5 and in base 2, 2/5 is a repeating decimal (0.0110011001100....). You have to do something to fit it in a double. The website I linked to (in effect) just truncated the decimal expansion  but maybe since the next bit in the infinite expansion would have been 1, Excel rounded up rather than truncated. I didn't realize that there were different rounding conventions in use. It might be interesting to use your function to reverse engineer Excel's rounding scheme when interpreting double literals.

Comment: I think "round-half-to-even" is the standard (default) IEEE rounding mode. Would need to actually look up the standard to make sure.

Comment: Thank you for this magnificent answer. If I could only be picky at one point: checking for `TypeName` will fail if used directly in a spreadsheet (which is what I think most people do) because it will return `Range` instead of `Single` or `Double`.

Comment: @ArthurAttout Good observation. Maybe the thing to do would be to replace "TypeName(float) = "Double"` by `TypeName(float) = "Double" Or TypeName(float) = "Range"` with the idea that only in VBA context do you need to handle `Single` (and even then rarely -- who uses single precision nowadays?).

Answer (score 0):

*Partial* Answer:

VBA bitwise operators are designed to work with integer or long data. Consider the following:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Single, y As Single
    x = 1#
    y = Not x
    Debug.Print y
    Debug.Print TypeName(Not x)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
-2 
Long
```

The first output line is the observed weirdness. The second line is the explanation of this weirdness. Evidently, `x` is converted to a long before being fed into `Not`. Interestingly, the following C program also prints -2:

```
int main(void){
    int x,y;
    x = 1;
    y = ~x;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    return 0;
}
```

(gcc uses 32 bit ints on my machine, so `int` here is equivalent to `Long` in VBA)

It *should* be possible to obtain what you want, but bitwise operators are not the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I think I have figured out how to do this in VBA (see my answer below for details).

Answer (score 0):

This function works for 64 bit double precision format:

```
Function IEEE754todouble(hexanumber As String) As Double

    If Left(hexanumber, 1) > 7 Then
        sign = 1
    Else
        sign = 0
    End If
    
    exponent = Val("&H" & (Left(hexanumber, 3))) Mod 2048
    
    mantissa = 16 ^ 8 * Val("&H" & Mid(hexanumber, 4, 5)) + Val("&H" & Right(hexanumber, 8))
    IEEE754todouble = (-1) ^ sign * 2 ^ (exponent - 1023) * (1 + 2 ^ -52 * mantissa)

End Function
```

If you need other formats, just change a few numbers in it and it should be alright.

I have put a double calculation in mantissa because the guy didn't want to know about a single `Val("&H" & Right(hexanumber, 13))`.