# Excel - why two equal integers have non-zero difference?

Tags: excel, floating-point, precision

I have `=2*10^15` in one cell which evaluates to `2,000,000,000,000,000` and I have `=2+2*10^15` in another cell which also evaluates to `2,000,000,000,000,000`, which is fine since the precision is only 15 digits. But when I then subtract one from another, I get back `2`, which I dont understand where it came from. As far as I can tell `2*10^15`has an exact binary representation, so I would have thought that when adding `2` to it, it just  "gets dropped". But it seems that my understanding is incorrect.

Actually, as far as I can tell, the binary representation of `2E+15` has `1` in places corresponding to powers of `2` equal to `{50,49,48,44,43,41,39,38,37,36,35,34,32,30,27,24,23,19,18,16}`, then why can't we just add another bit in place correspondign to power `1` and have an exact representation of `2+2E+15`?

Furthermore, if instead of `2` I add `1`, then the difference between `2*10^15` and `1+2*10^15` is `0` in Excel spreadsheet, but if I do the same calculation in Excel VBA, then I get back 1. What is that about?

I have read (several times) "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" but the discussion there seems to be focused on decimals rather than integers or I am just not getting it.

**Add 1**

I remembered that a while ago I wrote a function in VBA to get the binary representation of a number stored by Excel (the function could be found here
[Extract mantissa, exponent and sign data from IEEE-754 double in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909506/extract-mantissa-exponent-and-sign-data-from-ieee-754-double-in-vba/31922301#31922301)). So if I apply that function to `2 + 2E+15` it does return a binary with `1` in the 4th last place in mantissa (not sure why 4th, though) which is not there when the function is applied to `2E+15`, so it does seem that Excel simply choses to display number with 15 digits of precision even though the underlying stored floating number has a larger precision.

**Add 2**

It turns out that the reason that the extra bit in the mantissa of `2 + 2E+15` is in the 4th place (instead of 2nd) is that the mantissa gets "normalised" by dropping the leading (leftmost) bit (since it is always 1) and adjusting the length of the mantissa to 52 bits by shifting everything left which adds 2 0s at the end to the "simple" binary representation so that
`1110-0011-0101-1111-1010-1001-0011-0001-1010-0000-0000-0000-010`
becomes
`1100-0110-1011-1111-0101-0010-0110-0011-0100-0000-0000-0000-1000`.

It seems that due to this normalisation of the mantissa, the precision in the floating point double representation is actually 18 decimal places and, for example, the number `1.75 + 2E+15` can be represented exactly by mantissa `1100-0110-1011-1111-0101-0010-0110-0011-0100-0000-0000-0000-0111`.

Just need to figure out what is going on with the exponent... There is something called "biasing" being done to it...

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your message. I don't understand, however, what is the "typical issues that occur with floating point causes the problem" here. I thought 2E+15 had an exact floating point representation and hence there should be no rounding errors?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, but as I wrote in my post, I have read and re-read that document several times, but I still don't get it. I need an explicit explanation in terms of the actual bits in the floating point representation. Furthermore, this doesn't explain why I get different results in Excel spreadsheet and Excel VBA.

Comment: @pnuts That's fine, I understand how this sort of questions can be annoying, but I have not found a document clear enough for me to be able to reconstruct the whole process bit by bit. Only then I feel I will finally understand what is going on.

Comment: I think it is because Excel stores more digits than it displays, and then rounds to the displayed number of digits.  You can see the extra digit if you examine the xml that underlies the worksheet.

Comment: for the part with +1: read the "Example when a value reaches zero" section as this is the reason for showing 2 (difference is ok) but not 1 (difference is to small)... but much more confusing: do this with `+5` and the numbers are not equal anymore (while still just showing `2000000000000000`)

Comment: > "but the discussion there seems to be focused on decimals rather than integers or I am just not getting it. " - (Don't quote me on this, I'm not 100% sure), but if you are working with numbers in Excel with decimals, they are automaticaly converted to the Double type.

Comment: @Rawrplus Buy "focused on decimals" I meant it seems to be devoted to cases where a number cannot be represented exactly as a floating point, but as far as I can tell 2E+15 and 2+2E+15 can both be exactly represented as floating point number with bits in places corresponding to the powers of 2 shown in my post.

Comment: @Confounded I understand, what I was rather hinting at was, you're technically working with decimals as well and not integers. If you were to use the `MATH.FLOOR()` function, you would only then convert your two decimals to integers. After that, your substraction would be 0 ( tested it myself )

Comment: Apologies, the formula in my comment above should say `=FLOOR.MATH()` instead. That's what happens if you spend time switching between answering javascript and excel answers haha..

Comment: Re “As far as I can tell 2*10^15has an exact binary representation, so I would have thought that when adding 2 to it, it just "gets dropped".”: That is not the rule. The rule is that the exact mathematical result is rounded to the nearest representable result. As you note, 2+10^15 is exactly representable. So it is the result. Then (2+10^15)-10^15 is 2, which is the result you got, so there is no problem.

Comment: Re “Furthermore, if instead of 2 I add 1, then the difference between 2*10^15 and 1+2*10^15 is 0 in Excel spreadsheet, but if I do the same calculation in Excel VBA, then I get back 1.”: Microsoft’s exponentiation is notoriously bad, and it might differ between Excel and VBA (so 10^15 is not calculated exactly). Also, Excel may do some hidden rounding to nice decimal values in an attempt to cover up artifacts of binary floating point. It could take some detailed probing to figure out the specifics. For starters, ensure the full values of the cells are displayed, using 17+ digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for your messages. "(2+10^15)-10^15 is 2, which is the result you got, so there is no problem". The problem is that I don't understand why in both cases the result is displayed exactly as `2,000,000,000,000,000`, yet when I subtract the two number I get `2`.

Comment: @Confounded: Excel is displaying 2,000,000,000,000,002 as “2,000,000,000,000,000” either because it rounds numbers to “nice” decimal values for display as an attempt to conceal floating-point issues or because it is only rounding to some number of digits less than 16, which may be because that is a default, or it is some value you set for rounding, or that is all it is capable of. What (possibly bad) software **shows** you is not necessarily what it actually **has internally**. The bottom line is that Excel is not a platform for doing good mathematics.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So, if I were to use some other platform, would `2+(2E+15)` be displayed as `2,000,000,000,000,002`? So, the actual stored floating point number is an exact representation of `2+(2E+15)` but it just gets displayed with 15 digits precision? Does it mean that the precision of a double floating point is actually 16 decimal places, not 15 as it seems to be often stated? Lastly, is there a way to get at the actual number stored by Excel so that I can find out what it truly is?

Comment: Actually, a while ago I wrote this VBA function, so maybe I get use that to get at the number. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909506/extract-mantissa-exponent-and-sign-data-from-ieee-754-double-in-vba/31922301#31922301

Comment: The IEEE-754 64-bit binary format does store 2+10^15 exactly; in software that uses it, the number is exact. I cannot be sure what Excel. The format stores binary significands, not decimal digits. It properties are such that any 15-digit decimal numeral in in exponential format (15 digits times ten to some power) can be converted to the 64-bit binary floating-point format and back to a 15-digit number without error, as long as there is no overflow or underflow. Some numbers with more digits would survive a round trip, but not all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "any 15-digit decimal [...] can be converted to the 64-bit binary [...] and back [...] without error" this seems to explain why Excel only allows 15 decimal places of precision for displaying numbers as more than that is not guaranteed to be preserved by conversion.

Answer (score 1):

*So, I did some research, because I was intrigued by this question. While I can't quite guarantee you this answer is absolutely correct, it is most likely the closest we will get to a correct answer (unless some expert steps in).*

---

I'll try to dissect the question:

> I have =2*10^15 in one cell which evaluates to 2,000,000,000,000,000
>   and I have =2+2*10^15 in another cell which also evaluates to
>   2,000,000,000,000,000, which is fine since the precision is only 15
>   digits. But when I then subtract one from another, I get back 2, which
>   I dont understand where it came from. **As far as I can tell 2*10^15has
>   an exact binary representation, so I would have thought that when
>   adding 2 to it, it just "gets dropped".** But it seems that my
>   understanding is incorrect.

I think before we continue with anything, I think it's important to state, that **Excel** (or other MS products in general) **are notoriously underwhelming when it comes to float-point precision**. Some inaccuracies have to be accounted for here.

Also, this is actually one of those things, where the display is misleading. **Where the number that is displayed on your screen is actually not the same number that you are calculating with.** What I mean under that, in your case, the 2E+15 and 2E+15 albeit displayed the same are not necessarily the same number! (as weird as it sounds..) **They are just displayed as the same number, because the floating e^th position is so small, that excel considers it to be insignificant to be displayed**

> Furthermore, if instead of 2 I add 1, then the difference between
>   2*10^15 and 1+2*10^15 is 0 in Excel spreadsheet, but if I do the same
>   calculation in Excel VBA, then I get back 1. What is that about?

This is the trickiest part to answer. While I can't say this with certainty, my guess is, that is because the 1 at the end of the float-point arithmetic on the number 1 is rounded down to zero, while the 2 is left as it is. In general, this seems like one of those weird Excel float things, that are hard to explain without expertise and that just happen.

> I have read (several times) "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know
>   About Floating-Point Arithmetic" but the discussion there seems to be
>   **focused on decimals rather than integers** or I am just not getting it.

**You already are working with decimals (doubles to be precise).** The "Number" format in Excel automatically converts your number to a data-type depending on your need. **You are however absolutely not working with integers**

Integers are defined in a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. That means, our number far exceeds the max integer range. **If we were to convert both numbers to integers, both would be floored to the number 2,147,483,647, ending up with 0 difference** Closest representation of this I can reproduce is using the `=FLOOR.MATH()` formula, which rounds down to nearest multiple.

Last but not least, it's important to understand how the mathematical functions in excel are calculated. If you have a formula eg. `2+2*10^-15+2` the result calculated would be `4`. Why? Operator precedence: Where `*` has precedence over `+`, and `^` over `*`

So that ^ means, if we calculated `2+2*10^15 - 2*10^15`  is first concatenated together as a mathematical formula and calculated. That would result to `x.......2 - x........0`, albeit on our excel display it would show as `2E+15 - 2E+15`

I created the following table for illustration:

**Also note, using the** `=FLOOR.MATH()` **formula, we converted the doubles to the closest multiples [not integers!] (if we used `=INT()` we would only receive #VALUE error for exceeding integer range). The difference between** `=FLOOR.MATH(N1) - FLOOR.MATH(N2)` **is 0, although** `N2 - N1` **is not, because we are counting with different numbers and precision.** While this is not precisely the equivalent of working with integers (since they are not... obviously), they are the closest representation I can think of what would happen if we were to calculate with them.

[image]

One thing that however baffles me, the `=FLOOR.MATH()` function, of N2 seems to return with `.00` decimal, while N1 doesn't. Albeit, both should be precisely same numbers  (closest multiple). Not sure if this is just a formatting glitch or anythign of significance.

---

So to sum it up, I know this answer rather raises more questions than answers, but hopefully it will be a good  lift-off ramp for somebody else to answer this question for good and at least answered some of your questions if not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores numbers as double precision, which uses 64 bits in total. One bit is the sign, 11 bits are the exponent from -1024 to 1024 (in base 2) and the remaining 52 bits are for the fraction.

Using this method, the most number of significant figures that a number can be converted to a double precision and back again and GUARANTEED to be unchanged is 15. For 16 and 17 significant figures, this only holds for some numbers. I assume that this is why excel will only show data in the worksheet to 15 significant figures. Note that according to the specs, Excel will STORE values as a result of a formula to higher precision than it DISPLAYS; [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3]

Now in theory we should be able to exactly represent integers to 2^53 = 9,007,199,254,740,992. However, it appears Excel only stores integers exactly up to 2^50 = 1,125,899,906,842,624. Try subtracting this number from one plus this number and you get zero. Anything less than this number, you get one as expected. Then try 2^ 51 = 2,251,799,813,685,248, and subtract this number from 2 or 3 plus this number, you get zero. However if you subtract this number from 4 plus this number, you get 4. And so on.

Note that your value of 2E+15 lies between these values, so hence a difference of 1 won't register, but any greater difference will.

This article explains this explicitly:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format